# The base of a a pyramid $ABCDM$ is a rectangle $ABCD$ with sides $4\sqrt2$ and $4$

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

The base of a a pyramid $ABCDM$ is a rectangle $ABCD$ with sides $4\sqrt2$ and $4$. The triangles $ACM$ and $BDM$ are equilateral. Find the volume of the pyramid $ABCDM$.

The volume is given by $$V=\dfrac13.B.H,$$ so we are supposed to find the height $H$ of the pyramid and the area $B$ of the parallelogram $ABCD$ which is the base. $$B=ab=4\times4\sqrt2=16\sqrt2.$$
I am pretty sure that the projection $O$ of the apex $M$ onto the plane of the base is actually the intersection of the diagonals of $ABCD$, but I don't see how to show that. Can you help me?

Comment: The projection O must be on the center of the base (diagonals crossing) just because of symmetry

Comment: All $4$ sides from vertex to the base are equal. Find the altitude of equilateral triangle.

Comment: @MathLover, may I ask you if you can further explain what you meant, because I still don't see why the projection must be on the center of the base?

Comment: Say diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $O$. Given it is a rectangle , $AC = BD$. Hence $AC = BD = AM = BM = CM = DM$

Comment: Since the length of AC is not specified you have two solutions.